# How to get Mail.app raw message in the Automator?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

Need to get the raw message content from the OS X Mail.app a pass it to the next action.

Unfortunately - tested this -  and doesn't works: :(

[image: a]

I don't want select the "content" of the message, but want pass the `raw` content (what is base64 encoded) to the next action.

So, probably will need some applescript `action` betwwen the "Get Selected Mail Messages" and "New document".

Haven't idea how to do this...

The "New TextEdit doc" is only for tests, the real action will be an `perl` script, what will read the `raw message content` from the `stdin`.

Comment: I don't know if you can get the raw content using applescript. The first place you should start is by looking at Mail's applescript dictionary to find a command for that... if it exists. Just go to the File menu of AppleScript Editor, select "Open Dictionary", choose the Mail application and start looking. If you find a command then let us know and we can help you put something together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set theSource to {}
    tell application "Mail"
        repeat with aMessage in input
            set end of theSource to aMessage's source & return
        end repeat
    end tell

    return theSource as text
end run
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code for an AppleScript action to be run after the action "Get Selected Mail Messages".  It is to be placed within an action: "Run AppleScript"

```
-- This script accepts an input which is a list of message objects from Mail and returns their properties.
-- The properties returned are in the form of an AppleScript properties record.
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Mail"
        set output to {}
        repeat with thisMessage in input
            set output to output & (properties of thisMessage)
        end repeat
    end tell
    return output
end run
```

This script is progress I think, but its action returns a list of AppleScript records.  You would want to pick and choose which fields that you wanted in the AppleScript and return all of the Mail messages as text for the next action, your Perl script to be able to parse plain text and not have to deal with AppleScript records.

You can use the AppleScript above to peek at the record keys and values and then write a AppleScript to actually be used in your finished workflow which selects just the fields that you want.

-- Kaydell
kaydell@yahoo.com
http://learnbymac.com

Comment: Probably, you want to replace the line in the repeat loop with: set output to output & thisMessage's source & return